# Vertical scrolling in calendar

Tags: android, android-calendar, android-scroll

I am trying to create a calender for android 4.x devices where in the dates should get displayed in cell and month name at the top. now where ever user scroll up and down it should change the month (in short I would like to implement the functionality of changing month with up/down scrolling).

I have seen the same type of calendar control in HTC devices.

Any one has any idea how to implement this?

Comment: have you got the idea how to implement the calendar? you ask about how to create a calendar and scrolling or just how to create a vertical scrolling?

Comment: I just want to know how to implement vertical scrolling...

Answer (score 0):

I think that you use viewpager in this case, but in fact, it is vertical scrolling.

Should try using [DirectionalViewPager](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-DirectionalViewPager) - written by JakeWharton